# Block screen until redirect not ended

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect, blockui

Some pages in my web app load to many data from database, so redirect to this pages take some time.

Is there way to block screen (using jquery BlockUI) on every redirect (when it starts and until new page is being opened) ?

Adding `$.blockUI()` on every button click that makes redirect is a bit long.

Comment: do you use Ajax for receive new data ?

Comment: @MOB, in some case yes (this is easy case) and in some  - no... data loaded on page_load (webforms)